# Android -- put space between tab title and icon?

Tags: android, tabs, padding, margins

This is obviously too close.  Short of editing the icon file, how can I change it?

Code below is C# code (via Xamarin), but I'm sure I'll understand a Java answer just fine.

```
Android.App.ActionBar.Tab droidTab = this.ActionBar.NewTab();
droidTab.SetIcon(drawableBitmap);
droidTab.SetText(someString);
```

[image]

Comment: I guess you could add a space to the beginning of the string if you really don't want to edit the icon

Comment: I have used the "space before text" trick. It works. "Sometimes the simplest answer...", as they say. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible using the default API. You can, however, set a custom view. Using a `TextView` with a compound `Drawable`, you can set the `Drawable` padding using [`setCompoundDrawablePadding`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablePadding%28int%29):

```
TextView textView = new TextView(mContext);
textView.setText(someString);
textView.setCompoundDrawables(mDrawable, null, null, null);
textView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(mPaddingDp);

droidTab.setCustomView(textView);
```

Comment: for image you should rather call: `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()`

Answer (score 0):

[Check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4BtL.jpg) 
you can use the following code to achieve the spacing between icon and title

```
    TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tabOne.setText(tab1);
    tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.dash_today,0, 0, 0);
    tabOne.setCompoundDrawablePadding(icon_dp);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

    TextView tabTwo = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tabTwo.setText(tab2);
    tabTwo.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.dash_pipe,0, 0, 0);
    tabTwo.setCompoundDrawablePadding(icon_dp);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);`
```